# I get an error when I try to create a project using jhipster

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I installed nodejs and used

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

then used jhipster to create the project but it gives me error like this.

```
INFO! Using bundled JHipster
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:575
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/util/namespace' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-environment\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:267:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:603:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:643:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\utils\blueprint.js:19:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.0.0
```

My nodejs version is v20.0.0

I tried installing jhipster, deleting node_modules and forge again but nothing worked,how can I fix it?

Comment: Use Node 16 and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19627#issuecomment-1236110105) you should add `"./lib/util/namespace": "./lib/util/namespace.js"` this line to `"exports":` in this file:

`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-environment\package.json`

And then you can try again.